# I'm unable to scroll horizontally in my project

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, android-scrollview, react-native-cli, android-scrolling

I'm trying to create a story line that stacks horizontally on each other and you can scroll it horizontally from the beginning to the end but when I created it with the code below it didn't work at all.

The first line of code stacked it horizontally but wasn't able to scroll in it

```
showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={true},
```

Comment: What is your CSS? Is it possible that you have put an `overflow: none` (or something like this) somewhere?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.